# TabView Issue on iOS 17: Background Automatically Changes When Swiping Back

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios17

I have implemented a simple code with TabView and NavigationView. When navigating to another screen using NavigationLink, a problem arises. When I press the back button at the top, everything works fine. However, when I swipe from left to right to go back, the color of the TabView changes and becomes transparent.

This issue only occurs on iOS 17
all other simulators work fine (iOS 16 below).

```
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        
        TabView {
            ContentView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Menu", systemImage: "list.dash")
                }
            ContentView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Menu", systemImage: "list.dash")
                }
            ContentView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Menu", systemImage: "list.dash")
                }
        }   .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}
```

:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                ScrollView{
                    ForEach(0..<50) { item in
                        NavigationLink("SCREEN TWO") {
                            VStack(spacing: 10){
                                Text("If I click on the back button, the color of the tabview is OK")
                                
                                Text("If I slide the screen from left to right to go back, the color of the tabview changes")
                            }.padding()
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Video: https://streamable.com/wudk2n

Comment: Could not replicate your issue, no color change.
 All works well for me in my tests, on MacOS 14.1, Xcode 15, tested on real ios 17 devices (not Previews).
 It could be different on older systems. Note `NavigationView` is deprecated, use `NavigationStack`.

Comment: NavigationStack didn't work for me, I added a link to the video of the problem https://streamable.com/wudk2n

Comment: Have you tried using toolbar to set the color instead of leaving it on automatic

Answer (score 0):

I noticed what you were seeing. I am wondering if the structure of the View within the TabView needs to follow a specific pattern.

I found that just adding a `.navigationTitle` to the ScrollView in the `NavigationView` fixes the issue and the swipe back will maintain the bottom bar styling.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(0..<50) { item in
                    // Nothing changed in here
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("View One")
        }
    }
}
```